# Is it possible to run Cucumber example tables in parallel with webdriverio?

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io

I need to run a scenario multiple times with different data. I have a scenario with more than one example table and each example table has a different tag. Is it possible to run the scenario in parallel for each example table ?

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/wdio-cucumber-parallel-execution

Comment: Hi, thank you for sharing the link. This module allows to run multiple scenarios in parallel. In my case I only have one scenario with an example table.

Comment: @yosrO as far as I know each example table is a scenario.. so if you have one scenario with two example tables at the end you will have two scenarios.

ie:
`Feature: Homepage redirects
    As a user I want to navigate the homepage for a country
    Scenario Outline: as a user I want to visit the homepage in <nation>
        Given a user in <nation>
        Then I expect a redirect to a page having "isoCode" in the url
        Examples:
            | nation | isoCode |
            |  Italy   | it |
        Examples:
            | nation | isoCode |
            | Japan | jp |`

Comment: Thank you , I 've never thought of it from this angle. I will try the module and give feedback.